# Struts2 execAndWait interceptor warning following upgrade

Tags: java, struts2

I'm using **struts2** and have a long running process which utilizes the **execAndWait** interceptor. I recently upgraded to a newer release of struts and now get the following error in my log - I think it occurs each time the execAndWait calls back to the server...

> 06-Nov-2012 11:27:59 [org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper] WARN -
>   Could not find token mapped to token name struts.token

I've hunted round and seen the question asked on other sites but no satisfactory answers posted.

Comment: It is warning not error. Does it not working properly or what? Also are you using `Token` interceptor as well?

Comment: OK, have changed title to "warning". Everything seems to work fine, but the log file is filled with the warning and it obscures other potentially important information. token interceptor - not knowingly. Is it part of the defaultStack?

Comment: The ExecAndWait Interceptor does that. As Aleksandr points out - it's just a warning and although irritating and clogs the logfiles - it's not actually a problem.

Comment: Well it never used to do it which is why I raised it as a question. Given what you both say, perhaps I just need to modify the logging for org.apache.struts2.util.TokenHelper to `error` rather than `warn`.  Thanks both for your assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor` interceptor tries to find `token` and puts it in session because of the `Token` interceptor see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-1741.

As for the warning you could modify your log level for `TokenHelper` class.